# How to use select2 to build a tag function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to use `select2` to build a user `tag` function. With this we can add `tags` to users. It acheives the functions below:

> 1. When typing the tags, use an ajax to search the word in the database and list the match results;
> 2. We can choose the result to quickly add tags;
> 3. We can also press enter to add new tags that not exist in the database.
> 4. when submit, we just submit the tags themeselves.

However, use the example in the author's website, I can only achive `tags` or `ajax` search. I can't combine them together.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with that. I've just added `multiple="multiple"` attribute to `select` in github example and I have ajax + tags functionality.
Additionally I've added `tags:true` option  to let user create his own tags.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  tags:true,        
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      var newData = [];
        $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {
            newData.push({
                id: item.id  //id part present in data 
              , text: item.name  //string to be displayed
            });
        });
        return { results: newData };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Please also note that I've modified `processResults` function in order to make it work in jsfiddle.

Here's working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8bg2y0q3/1/